# - - - is converting to — while passing to href

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html

I am creating a link URL in my website and using it in the blog as href for anchor tag.

This is how my URL looks in website

https://www.mywebsite.com/sets/get-the-look-bella-hadid---london/4558

After passing it to the blog the link parse to something like this

https://www.obsessory.com/sets/get-the-look-bella-hadid—london/4558

I don't understand why is it converting --- to — ?

Have anybody faced same problem anywhere ?

People voting to close the question, try and understand the question.

Comment: What type of blog is it? Wordpress? Tumblr? etc.

Comment: You haven't actually posted any code, or alluded to what programming languages you're using. No-one is going to be able to help you if you don't post some useful information.

Comment: This is an issue with your blogging software, not an actual programming problem.

Comment: blog type is wordpress

Comment: @fubar You're right but it's just JS & HTML, when I pass the url it's same as 1st URL and when I see in Elements in chrome dev tool than it's changed to 2nd

Comment: @Rakeschand - you don't state how you created the URL, what you're passing it to, or anything. But it seems you have a solution, so no matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using WordPress? The editor for text handles hypens and dashes automatically - as many other editors out there do.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize this is doing the magic in WordPress.

You might need to insert your link as link instead. See https://en.support.wordpress.com/links/

Or in functions.php you can disable the magic (but a real link is the better choice):

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a programming problem (and therefore, isn't appropriate for StackOverflow), it's a problem with your blogging software.

You're most likely pasting the text into a rich text editor like WordPress has and it's converting the text on you. The problem is, WordPress and other software try to convert raw URLs into links, but they also try to make the content pretty. By prettifying the content, it's converted multiple dashes into an em dash. Then, when it tries to turn that into a link, it only gets part way because the em dash is not a valid URL character.

To work around it, don't rely on the editor to convert links for you. Write some text you'd like for the link, highlight it, then use whatever "link" button is in the editor to make it an actual link.

You might also be able to use a raw HTML editor or a Markdown editor (like StackOverflow has) to craft the link properly.

Comment: Thanks @Soviut I'll try what you wrote.